# Regular Expression for matching string like: "<any_string>+<any_string>+<any_string>"

Tags: regex

Regular Expression for matching string like:

```
"<any_string>+<any_string>+<any_string>"?
```

Comment: Can `any_string` include the character `>`?

Comment: Is that the same "any string" 3 times, separated by + signs?

Comment: This is not clear. Can you please post some examples of input and output? Are you trying to validate or match?

Comment: acceptable strings:
abc
abc+xyz
abc+ef+xyz
abc+xyz+mno+pqr

Comment: edit that into your original question. Only 1 of those strings matches your original `"<any_string>+<any_string>+<any_string>"`. Also, what about the string `"++"`? Should that match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as simple as:

```
.*\+.*\+.*
```

the `.*` matches any_string until the `\+` matches a "+" symbol.

Comment: or adding a not-greedy: .*?\+

Comment: Those are all valid suggestions. From the OP's followup comment, it looks like this regex doesn't actually do what he wants (but it does do what he described). I'll edit it once he gives all the needed information, and include your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

here's a non-regex way. In your favourite language, split on "+", check the length of array to be 3. pseudocode:

```
s = split(mystring,"+")
if length(s) = 3 then
  .....
end if
```

To be more "accurate", split on ">+<"

Comment: It's not clear what the OP wants. This approach matches `<i++>=<i-->` for example.

Comment: more efficient is a simple `if mystring.count("+") == 2 then ...` (or ">+<")

Answer (score 1):

This matches `S+S+S` where all three occurrences of `S` is the same string, which is `<` and `>` surrounding any (possibly empty) string:

```
(<[^>]*>)\+\1\+\1
```

In other words, this matches:

```
<a>+<a>+<a>
```

But it doesn't match

```
<a>+<b>+<a>
```

`S` must be surrounded by `<` and `>`; it can contain `+`. So this matches:

```
<a+b>+<a+b>+<a+b>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
[\w\\+]*
```

Comment: That matches an empty string and it matches '+', but it doesn't match ' + + '.  It's broken.

Comment: For some reason the \\ doesnt come out with the edit, i have to edit and use double slash. It shoulds work

Comment: that won't match any *string*, just any *word characters* (Though maybe that's what the OP actually wants)

Comment: Yeah if string is what he is after, then use . otherwise if only word character then use \w

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this

```
/.*\+.*\+.*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If `any_string` would not contain the delimiter character `>`, you can easily do that using:

```
<([^>]+)>\+<([^>]+)>\+<([^>]+)>
```

`$1`, `$2` and `$3` in the match would contain the 1st, 2nd and the 3rd strings respectively. This regex doesn't allow empty strings - change `([^>]+)` to `([^>]*)` to allow empty strings between `<` and `>`.